# Specific Histogram R

Tags: r

How to do this kind of histogram in R?
[image: expected]

I tried

```
plot(df$Value, type = 'l')
polygon(df$Value,  col='red')
```

But the result is not needful

[image: result]

Comment: please make a reproducible example `plot(x <- c(0, runif(100, -1, 1), 0), type = 'n'); polygon(x, col = 'red', border = NA)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to offer another possible approach, you can build this plot fairly easily using base R graphics. I usually prefer to build plots manually using base R graphics because it allows precise control over all aspects of the plot. Furthermore, I think that when you spend time contemplating exactly how these kinds of plots need to be built up from primitive graphics elements, it completely demystifies them, by which I mean you develop the understanding that they really are quite simple in terms of conceptual and graphical structure. In this particular case, we can create the primary graphical element (referring to the histogram bars themselves) using a single vectorized call to `segments()`.

```
## generate data
set.seed(5468L);
N <- 7700L;
df <- data.frame(Value=round(cumsum(c(0.07,runif(N-1L,-0.001,0.001))),5L));

## precompute plot parameters
xlim <- c(1L,N);
ylim <- c(-0.08,0.1);
xticks <- seq(xlim[1L],xlim[2L],276L);
yticks <- seq(ylim[1L],ylim[2L],0.02);

## plot
plot(NA,xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,xaxs='i',yaxs='i',axes=F,ann=F); ## set range, nothing else
abline(h=yticks,col='lightgrey'); ## horizontal grid lines
segments(seq_len(N),0,y1=df$Value,lwd=0.3,col='#5599CC'); ## histogram bars
text(xticks,-0.005,xticks,adj=c(1,0.5),col='#666666',srt=90,xpd=T); ## custom x-axis in plot
mtext(yticks,2L,0.5,at=yticks,adj=1,las=1L,col='#666666'); ## custom y-axis on margin
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions with ggplot2

```
a <- arima.sim(list(ar=.9), n = 200)#simulated data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:200, a = as.vector(a))

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = a)) + geom_area()
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = a)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, position  = "dodge")
```